# How to enable registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a website that works without problems. Here is the routes file:

```
Testpager::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :news,      only: [:index, :show]
  resources :documents, only: [:index, :show]

  namespace :admin do
    resources :documents, only: [:index, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update, :new, :create]
    resources :news,      only: [:index, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update, :new, :create]
    get "admin" => 'documents#index'
  end

  get "contacts/index"
  get "services/index"
  get "index/index"
  get "admin/index"

  root 'index#index'
end
```

I would like to add a registration system. To do this I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

My actions are:

1. I installed the Devise gem.
2. Ran `rails g devise:install`
3. Added this to application.html.erb:

   ```
   <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
   ```
4. Ran `rails g devisw User`
5. Ran `rake db:migrate`
6. Ran `rails server`
7. I opened the URL `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up`

I got the following error message:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Registrations#new
Showing /home/kalinin/rails/testpager/app/views/shared/_nav_main.html.erb where line #6 raised:
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"devise/index"}
Extracted source (around line #6):      
    <ul>
        <li>
            <%= link_to 'index', controller: "index", action: "index" %>
        </li>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

Here is the controller:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

The view for IndexController exists.

Comment: Don't name your controller 'IndexController', it will just lead to confusion. Name it after the resource it represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link About Adding Custom fields to a Devise registration: http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html. What you will need to do is set up a Registrations Controller that inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController. This quick tutorial is easy to read and understand.